# Am I computing Jacobi Iteration wrong?

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

To solve the system
$$2x_1-\hphantom2x_2+\hphantom2x_3=-1\\2x_1+2x_2+2x_3=\hphantom-4\\-x_1-x_2+2x_3=-5$$
with Jacobi iteration, we let
$$A=2I_3,\qquad L+U=\begin{bmatrix}0&-1&1\\2&0&2\\-1&-1&0\end{bmatrix},\qquad b=\begin{bmatrix}-1\\4\\-5\end{bmatrix}$$
so that $(A+L+U)\cdot x=b$ is our system.  Since $A^{-1}=\frac12I_3$, the Jacobi iteration is
$$\text{iter}(x)=A^{-1}(b-(L+U)x)=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{x_2}2-\frac{x_3}2-\frac12\\-x_1-x_3+2\\\frac{x_1}2+\frac{x_2}2-\frac52\end{bmatrix}$$
Certainly the exact solution $(1,2,-1)$ is a fixed point of $\text{iter}$, but when I try to use it it never converges.  Here is a plot of the iteration spiraling away from the solution:

[image: no converge]

The code to make that in Mathematica is

```
With[{A = 2 IdentityMatrix@3, 
  LpU = {{0, -1, 1}, {2, 0, 2}, {-1, -1, 0}}, b = {-1, 4, -5}}, 
 With[{iter = Inverse@A.(b - LpU.#) &, init = {10, -10, -1}}, 
  Graphics3D[{Arrow@NestList[iter, init, 20], Point@init}, 
   Boxed -> False]]]
```

Have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iteration matrix $-D^{-1}(L+U)$ has eigenvalues $\pm i \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $0$. This means that the iteration function $G(x)=D^{-1}b-D^{-1}(L+U)x$ is not contractive in any norm and the fixed point method (Jacobi's method is just the fixed point method for this particular choice of $G$) cannot be convergent for an arbitrary initial approximation.

Comment: Aren't the eigenvalues $\pm i\frac{\sqrt5}2$ and $0$?  Though is it only the magnitudes of these that matter? (i.e. $|i\sqrt5/2|>1$)

Comment: @Adam Yes, thanks, I missed the $i$.

Answer (score 3):

Your implementation is not wrong! But Jacobi algorithm is guaranteed to converge only for **strictly diagonally dominant system of linear equations**. [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_method)

Your system is not strictly dominant. So it's not too surprising that it diverges...

---

Though compare this question I answered a few days ago, where Gauss Seidel method is applied to a non-diagonal dominant system, but it converged. ([Can non diagonally dominant system of linear equations be solved by jacobi or guass seidel method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4453704/can-non-diagonally-dominant-system-of-linear-equations-be-solved-by-jacobi-or-gu/4453793#4453793))

Comment: The condition you mention is only a sufficient condition, and this may not be apparent from the way you phrased it. The Jacobi methods converges for any initial approximation if and only if the spectral radius of $D^{-1}(L+U)$ is less than 1, which holds for a class of matrices much wider than strictly diagonally dominant matrices. If you don't impose convergence for all initial approximations, you get an even wider set of matrices.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use [Jacobi Iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_method#Description) to play with this equation, you can rewrite it as $$\begin{bmatrix}2&-1&1\\2&2&2\\-1&-1&2\end{bmatrix}^T\begin{bmatrix}2&-1&1\\2&2&2\\-1&-1&2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2&-1&1\\2&2&2\\-1&-1&2\end{bmatrix}^T\begin{bmatrix}-1\\4\\-5\end{bmatrix},$$ or as $$\begin{bmatrix}9&3&4\\3&6&1\\4&1&9\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}11\\14\\-3\end{bmatrix},$$ wich has a [diagonally dominant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_method#Convergence) matrix.

You can find related results searching for "[\(Ax=b\)  jacobi method](https://www.searchonmath.com/result/?q=%5C%28Ax%3Db%5C%29%20%20jacobi%20method%20)" on SearchOnMath.